# RegEx to match two specific Distinguished Names in Certificate string

Tags: regex, certificate, match

I trying to find or build regex search expression so that the following two options( and only these two options) could be matched.  This is to check a certificate from either of two organisations.

CN.*, DC=Adomain1, DC=Adomain1, DC=local

CN.*, DC=Bdomain1, DC=local

I need to figure out how to match either of these strings but nothing else.  I am absolutely hopeless at regex and is taking me ages to work this stuff out...  Thought someone out there could probably do this in 1 min prob....

Thanks to anyone who can help out.

Cheers

Comment: Can you share in some place hole file in witch you search. then i will do it for you.

Comment: I am actually doing this as part of a pattern search on a F5 appliance so it search process is being done by the F5 when a client presents its certificate.  The F5 I think will use this regex expression to choose the right certificate from the clients store.  oh and thanks heaps for your help